# How to acknowledge two equally valid answers as accepted?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I asked a question here: [JQuery - Dynamically Adding a New DIV Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590873/jquery-dynamically-adding-a-new-div-element) and two people provided equally valid, functional answers. One provided the Fiddle for it and another provided the much needed line by line analysis and mod to make it work. Either one of these would have been a great answer that would have resolved my issue.

How do I pick which one to mark as the answer? We can't mark both can we? I have upvoted both as the least I can do but how do I resolve this dilemma? Please advise.

Comment: Its your decision but if I were you, I would go with the answer which is most helpful for future visitors (to me its the one explaining instead of just giving the code)

Answer (score 2):

That's entirely up to you.  There is no way of marking both answers as *the* accepted answer.  You will have to choose one based on whichever you feel *best* answers your question.

You can still upvote any answers you felt were helpful, even if you don't mark them as accepted.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I did search but didn't find that and it sort of addresses my issue but here is the thing. They have answered the question but not using the same code and not in the same way and they have both put equal work into it, so I find it hard to decide which one to mark as accepted because I ended up using a mix of their answers to minimize the code. So they both contributed to me equally and to mark just based on rep or who came in first I find to be unfair to the other. I hate this.

Comment: Can you take a look please and based on your experience tell me which one you think fits as the better answer considering the site guidelines? Please.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ it is of course your decision but if you're looking for advice I note Ariels answer actually attempts to explain why/how the code works where as the other answer just dumps code. Assuming both are correct then the answer with explanation seems more helpful from my perspective